# Granular Storage authorization in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

Can Amplify’s Storage resource apply permissions beyond the basic levels of private, protected, and public?

Protected and public are too permissive for our needs, but private is too tight.

Is there any way to tie access to certain Cognito attributes, just as we can do with the GraphQL models?

For example, could one designate a set of files that can be readable by anyone with a custom:companyID attribute of "12345"? Or mandate that all files are readable/writable by anyone in the "Admins" usergroup?

Comment: Were you every able to find a workaround for this?

Comment: Still a work in progress. I don't think we're goin to be able to use Storage to achieve the security we need. Instead I think we'll use a custom API to upload files to S3. We will save certain metadata with the file. To retrieve a file, we'll also have to use a custom API that will perform checks on the metadata and compare it to the claims of the requester to verify whether they have access to the document.